# POST Action always receives null via Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

For the past few hours, I've been trying to send a Json object via Ajax to my Action, the data reaches the action, but its value is null.

I'll be happy to update the questions, if any additional information is required.

Thanks,
Ilan

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".button-search").click(function () {
        var manufacturer= $("#Manufacturer").val();
        var model = $("#Model").val();
        var rentPrice = $("#RentPrice").val();
        var gear = $("#Gear").val();
        var year = $("#Year").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Car/SearchResults",
            data: {
                Manufacturer: manufacturer,
                Model: model,
                RentPrice: rentPrice,
                Gear: gear,
                Year: year,
            },
            success: function (results) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        })
    });
})
```

Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchResults(CarSearchModel model)
    {
        var searchResults = CarHelper.CarSearch(model.Manufacturer, model.Model, model.RentPrice, model.Year, model.Gear);

        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = searchResults;

        return result;
    }
```

Class:

```
public class CarSearchModel
    {
        [StringLength(4, ErrorMessage="Maximum 4 digits.")]
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string Gear { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Display(Name="Rent Price")]
        public int RentPrice { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Delay Fee")]
        public int DelayFee { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Rent Date")]
        public DateTime RentDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Return Date")]
        public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: try returning a hardcoded string

Comment: your Ajax call uses a field called `Manufacturer`, but your model has a field by the name of `model.Manufactor`. Is this a typo when you formatted the question, or an actual code difference?

Comment: @llan Ezersky first try to send some dummy values for Manufacturer: manufacturer,Model,RentPrice,Gear,Year if then working correctly then check all values of the elements. also instead of this("/Car/SearchResults") use "@Url.Action("SearchResults","Car")" also add   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' to list.

Comment: I formatted the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest checking the ModelState to see if there are any type conversion errors.

I believe you'll receive an error such as the one below.

```
The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'xxx' failed because
no type converter can convert between these types.
```

This can occur due to your controller argument name being the same one as the 'Model' property name.

Comment: Thanks, changing the argument name worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add:

```
dataType: "json"


       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Car/SearchResults",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                Manufacturer: manufacturer,
                Model: model,
                RentPrice: rentPrice,
                Gear: gear,
                Year: year,
            },
            success: function (results) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        })
```

Comment: datatype changes the type of the *returned* item. Not the *sent* item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this should work for you, also you need to open your Dev Tools (F12) and add error details you are getting if any.

```
$(function () {
    $(".button-search").click(function () {
        var manufacturer= $("#Manufacturer").val();
        var model = $("#Model").val();
        var rentPrice = $("#RentPrice").val();
        var gear = $("#Gear").val();
        var year = $("#Year").val();

        var input = {
            Manufacturer: manufacturer,
            Model: model,
            RentPrice: rentPrice,
            Gear: gear,
            Year: year
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Car/SearchResults",
            data: JSON.stringify(input),
            success: function (results) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        })
    });
})
```

This is related you may find it helpful : [How to call web api method using jquery ajax in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://yassershaikh.com/how-to-call-web-api-method-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc-4/)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but still there's no change in the output.

Comment: Do you added java script references(JQuery) correctly?

Comment: Yes, all of the references are included in the scripts folder, bundled in the config and rendered in the layout, the external script to this current view is located inside in a script tag.

Comment: @llan Do you try with dummy values?

Comment: I tried to send hard-codded values through the ajax, no change.

Comment: The console is clean.

Comment: Chck network tab. What is the response code ? Check the data being sent

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/Car/SearchResults
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error, becuase of the null reference I get

Comment: The class has been added to the question.

Comment: @llan Ezersky see the answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself to develop similar code to this with sample application, here is the working code of the Similar Ajax result.
Note: Here ActionResult should be JsonResult

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Index(Practice model)
 {
  // Whatever your logic
  return Json(new { msg = model.PracticeName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

And Ajax Request like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index","Practices")',
                type: 'Post',
                contenttype:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: {
                    PracticeId: $('#PracticeName').val() ,
                    PracticeName:$('#PracticePercentage').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And my sample view is like this,

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.Practice

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Practice</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PracticeName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PracticeName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PracticeName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PracticePercentage)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PracticePercentage)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PracticePercentage)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Create" id="btn" name="btn" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And My sample Model like here

```
 public class Practice
    {
        public int PracticeId { get; set; }
        public string PracticeName { get; set; }
        public string PracticePercentage { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope this help you to solve the problem.

**UPDATE:**

In your scenario Remove the Validation Attribute of "Year" from the ViewModel and try again It is working fine.Also Rename the Model attribute from the view model for conflicts.

It is like this,

```
class CarViewModel  {  

public int Year { get; set; }

public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

public string Gear { get; set; }

public int RentPrice { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Delay Fee")]
public int DelayFee { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Rent Date")]
public DateTime RentDate { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Return Date")]
public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little change in your code and it is working for me.

**Model**

```
public class CarSearchModel
    {
        public string Manufacturer {get;set;}
        public string Model {get;set;}
        public string RentPrice {get;set;}
        public string Year {get;set;}
        public string Gear {get;set;}
    }
```

**Action method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResults(CarSearchModel model1)
{
    return Json(model1); 
}
```

**Jquery Post**

```
$(function(){
    $('.button-search').click(function(){

        var data1= {    
                        Manufacturer: 'Audi',
                        Model: 'Q8',
                        RentPrice: '100',
                        Gear: '4',
                        Year: '2001'

                };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="SearchResults", controller="Home"})',
                data: JSON.stringify(data1),
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(resp) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(resp));
                    }
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

You just need to stringify your json parameters. Build and run, it will work.